# Newer notifications interrupt old notifications' sounds

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

In my Android app it is quite usually that more than one notification arrives at the same time or at least within one or two seconds. Basically I've got two types or better priorities of notifications: Informative notifications (just some information for the user, low priority, device's default notification sound) and very important notifications (such as alarms, calls, etc.; with high/max priority, using a custom sound which lasts a couple of seconds).

I am using `notification.sound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION) / customUri;` and I set the priority with `NotificationCompatBuilder(Context).setPriority(NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW/IMPORTANCE_MAX`.

When a high priority notification arrives the sound starts to play but stops as soon as the low priority notification shows up.

Is there any possibility of preventing the lower priority messages to interrupt the high priority notification's sound? 
I first thought about using the MediaPlayer but in my opinion that won't be the correct way.. So any other ideas?

Thanks in advance :)

Edit: I forgot to mention that I do not want to delay any notification until the other notification's sound has finished, because the new informative notification might also be useful for the user. So I would prefer to skip or queue the sound of low priority message(s) when a high priority message's sound is playing.

Comment: Delay raising the low-priority notifications until N seconds after the high-priority notifications are done, where N is greater than or equal to the ringtone duration.

Comment: I guess this would be a possible solution for those situations but it wouldn't be "perfect" in my opinion. I added some short words about this in my post. Anyway thanks for this idea.

Comment: `customUri` and the rest of your question suggests a custom ringtone. Suppose each is 3 minutes long. You raise the high-priority notification, starting its ringtone. 2 seconds later, the low-priority event arrives, and so you show its notification sans ringtone, planning to play the ringtone separately (e.g., `MediaPlayer`) 2:58 later. User swipes open the notification shade, stopping the 1st ringtone, but you do not know this. User sees both notifications, but does not delete the 1st one. You play 2nd ringtone minutes after the user sees 2nd notification. Seems odd to me.